# The rational sum

Tags: rational-numbers, binary-operations

Let $x=\frac{a}{b}$ and $y=\frac{c}{d}$ be two rational numbers with fractions in simplest form.
Can we express $\frac{a+c}{b+d}$ in terms of $x$ and $y$ only.
Also, Can $\frac{a+c}{b+d}$ be a binary operation in set $Q$ of rational numbers?

Comment: Is simplest form well-defined: which of these is in simplest form $(-2)/3$, $2/(-3)$?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown simplest form means that numerator and denominator are co-prime and $-$ sign is always on numerator

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "in terms of $x$ and $y$ only". In the formal mathematical sense, the answer is YES, since given your additional constraints in your comment, the result is uniquely determined by $x$ and $y$ (not just the *values* of $x$ and $y,$ of course) and is called the [mediate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mediant_(mathematics)) of $x$ and $y.$ However, one could further ask (and I suspect this is what you really want to know) whether this function can be defined by using some kind of algebraic formula or by some kind of "elementary function defined" formula.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro if i have $x$ and $y$ only can i find the rational sum using only those values?

Comment: My point is that talking about the values of $x$ and $y$ is not really correct since, for example, "the value of $x$ is $2/3$" and "the value of $x$ is $4/6$" are mathematically equivalent, but correspond to different values of $a$ and $b.$ And if you instead phrase the question as "is the value of $\frac{a+c}{b+d}$ determined when $a$ and $b$ are coprime positive integers and $\ldots$", then the answer is clearly YES. Also, asking if one expression can be expressed in terms of other expressions/variables requires some more information about what "can be expressed" means. **(continued)**

Comment: For example, when both $x$ and $y$ are restricted to positive real numbers, then $xe^y + ye^x = 5$ determines $y$ as a function of $x,$ and also $x$ as a function of $y$ (try graphing this equation, or notice that implicit differentiation shows both $dy/dx$ and $dx/dy$ are negative. However, most people would say that we cannot express $y$ in terms of $x,$ despite the fact that for each value of $x$ there exists exactly one value of $y.$ (If someone wants to bypass "cannot express" by using the Lambert function or something, then appropriately use some trig. functions, Bessel functions, etc.)